# Javascript window.location.href in chrome doesn't work after POST method

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have change password html form. When user submits that form, I write another `<p> </p>` element to tell user changed his password or did not and add link to Login page.  Both link to Login and Cancel button does the same - redirect to login page. However, after POST method when I click Cancel/redirect to login buttons the screen just keeps loading and never really redirects you there. If I click submit button once again, it sends POST request again so this button works fine no matter how many requests I send. What's wrong with redirection? I can't seem to figure that out. I checked that in Firefox and it seems to work there fine. My code is below:

```js
document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function(event) {
  window.location.href = "/login";
};

var token = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

function validate() {
  var responseText = document.getElementById('error_id');

  var password = document.forms["reset-pasword"]["new_password"].value;
  var confirmPassword = document.forms["reset-pasword"]["repeat_password"].value;
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    error = "Passwords do not match";
    responseText.innerHTML = error;
    responseText.className = "error_text";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById("btn_change").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var responseText = document.getElementById('error_id');

  if (validate() != true)
    return;
  var password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
  var request = {
    token: token,
    password: password
  };
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/update', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = (res) => {
    response = res['target']['response'];
    if (response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      responseText.innerHTML = response.message;
      responseText.className = "error_text";
    } else {
      responseText.innerHTML = "Password changed succesfully. <a href=\"/login\">Login</a>";
      responseText.className = "success_text";
    }
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(request));
};
```

```html
<body onload="document.getElementById('reset-pasword').focus();">
  <div class="box" id="change_password_panel">
    <form name="reset-pasword" id="reset-pasword">
      <label for="password">New password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="new_password" name="new_password" required />

      <label for="password">Repeat new password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="repeat_password" name="repeat_password" required />
      <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;margin-top: 10px;">
        <div style="float: left;"><button id="btn_change" class="button">Change password</button>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;"><button id="btn_cancel" type="button" class="button">Cancel</button></div>
      </div>

      <p id="error_id"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also, if I click `Cancel` button first, before clicking Submit, redirection works fine.

If I put `window.location.href = "/login";` inside `xhr.onload` in if and else statements it doesn't work either. So the problem is could be with POST method? I'm really lost with this one..

This is network when I click 'Cancel' before submitting form:
[image]

and this is after:
[image]

It doesn't even have 'login' in it... 
 I also tried

```js
document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/login/default.html')
            .then(window.location.href = "default.html");
    };
```

but it seems it just goes inside `window.location.href` and never goes out there

Comment: If no response, the change was successful? That sounds a bit dangerous...

Comment: Your code should work. Any console messages?

Comment: No console messages, just screen loading forever...

Comment: May the problem be with the login page, not password change?

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül I don't think so, If I click cancel button when submit button wasn't clicked it works fine

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Literally nothing, no error. It never finishes loading for some reason

Comment: How did you make your routes? What html `/login` is supposed to show?

Comment: Can you share with us a screenshot of the network inspector when pressing cancel?

Comment: @YoannPicquenot added

Comment: @user122222 Could you try adding before `window.location.href = "/login";` in the `btn_cancel` function: `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @YoannPicquenot already tried that... no success either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198470/discussion-between-yoann-picquenot-and-user122222).

Comment: Have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem once and still I don't know what was wrong, but I solved this problem adding `<a>` tag agin adding event to the button.

```
document.getElementById("btn_cancel").innerHTML = "<a href='/login'>Cancel</a>";
```

Comment: Sadly, did not fixed my issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
  setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "/login;"},500);
```

or

```
  window.location.assign("/login");
```

Comment: Did not help :(